# Ubuntu 16.04.3 DSN resolve issue

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

i am new to Ubuntu. i have created DNS server in my VPS ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com and both pointing to 123.123.11.123. i have assigned these name servers against my example.com domain name DNS settings but i couldn't access my website any where in the world. i can access my domain inside my server ($dig example.com @localhost) but couldn't ping my domain name or name servers from other computers. Did i missed anything here. Kindly suggest me if i missed anything.

i have tried enabling the firewall ports using bellow command
$sudo ufw allow in on eth0 to any port 80

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting? Did you purchase the domain name you are trying to use from a source such as NameCheap or something similar?